# Bash script for taking a screenshot, renaming and moving

Tags: bash, shell

First bash script and I'm running into some issues. I want to take a screenshot, then change the name of the .png to a random number (so that pictures don't overwrite). After it's renamed I want to move the picture to my dropbox folder.

This is what I've got:

```
#!/bin/bash

#Take screenshot
import -window root $HOME/screenshot.png

#Move to dropbox folder
mv $HOME/screenshot.png $HOME/Dropbox/Max-Max/$RANDOM.png
```

When I run it dropbox is getting some kind of something because my taskbar icon indicates a file transfer. When I open up the folder however, nothing's there.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Try moving screenshot to some local folder and see it this works correctly

Comment: maybe the script is running as a different user - so ending up in a different $HOME folder's Dropbox - or nowhere

Comment: Does the `Max-Max` subdirectory already exist? Can you see any error messages `mv` might be printing?

Comment: From what I got from sites I read, $RANDOM already generates a random number. No need to define it?
Also: All folders already exist

Comment: Right - wanted to make sure you weren't overwriting $RANDOM with something else somewhere.  The script above worked for me.

Comment: hmmm. Could it be something to do with dropbox? I doubt it but it looks find to both of us. There is only 1 user on my box (named max), so I don't think that's the issue. I also just checked and that is the correct location of bash

Comment: @esnyder: $RANDOM is a bash buildin. Btw.: Works for me, when I rename the path to my needs.

Comment: Ya, user unknown, I should've phrased it better.  The script works after I created a Max-Max in Dropbox without issue.  I was wondering if he redefined $RANDOM - it won't work if you try to make a ".png"

Comment: How do you invoke the script? `./name` or `bash name` or `sh name`?

Comment: I invoke using bash filename.sh

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of $RANDOM use $(date|tr " :" _)
Much more useful

Comment: could you explain that command?
Also, I tried it and still nothing happens

Comment: @MaxMackie, the idea is to add a date_time string to the filename. The problem I see with AmitabhK's idea is that you wind up with a messy string like Mon_Mar_28_14_04_21_CDT_2011. Format the date cmd output to something that naturally sorts. try $(/bin/date +%Y%m%d.%H%M%S) which gives you something like $(/bin/date +%Y%m%d.%H%M%S) (currently 20110328.140656). BTW, enclosing a command in $( ... ), is called command substitution. Whatever cmd you are executing will have the results of the command substituted into the command line before it is execute. Turn on set -vx to see it work.

Comment: shelter that solved it! no idea why but it works now :) thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with scrot like this:

```
scrot -e 'mv $f ~/Dropbox/Max-Max'
```

But your script looks fine... Try to create an empty file first to make sure your dropbox functions fine.

```
echo > ~/Dropbox/Max-Max/testfile
```

Answer (score 0):

The commands you're using are correct. The only way it could fail is if Max-Max doesn't exist. mv moves and renames files among existing directories -- mv cannot create directories.